# How to set up a Intellij run-configuration for a Vert.x 3.2.x project with gradle?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vert.x

I know there has been questions about this topic earlier, but I thought I'd 'ask' one more time as I could not get my run configuration to work from what I read...

What was obvious from the earlier postings here on Stack Overflow was that you should use the following:

- Main class: **io.vertx.core.Launcher**
- Program arguments: **run**

My problem was that I got this warning when setting up a run configuration:

[image: Warning in the Intellij run configuration dialog box]

When trying to set up a similar project using Maven everything was working flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Intellij specifies 3 modules when creating a Gradle based project.

[image: Gradle project structure, Modules]

The trick is to pick the right module in the 'Run/Debug Configuration', 'Use classpath of module' field . I originally selected the base module ('ldaptest') where I should have selected the 'main' module.

[image]